# Confusion over Facebook Messenger's Page Scoped IDs (PSID)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm just having a little confusion over the scope types of IDs returned by Facebook's API (v2.10).

I'm requesting the conversations of a page by calling this endpoint,

`$endpoint = /{PAGE_ID}/conversations?fields=id,thread_key,participants,senders,snippet,can_reply`

and in the `participants` and `senders` field, according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/conversation#readfields), I'm presented with an `'id' => string`. I have no idea what scope this ID pertains to.

When I'm accepting a [message webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/message), I can access the sender's PSID.

The problem is I'm trying to match up whether the page is being messaged by the *same* person but I can't because the IDs returned by those two are **different**.

Help?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching/

Comment: I don't think the sender ID from the conversation is _app scoped_ nor _page scoped_, which means the ID matching wouldn't work?

Comment: @DannyNg looks that way here too.

Comment: The ID matching wouldn't work. Doesn't seem like it's possible to get the PSID in this context.

Answer (score 0):

As of the API v3.2, I've noticed the senders/participant's ID match the same PSIDs provided by the webhook. The may have been different in v2.10 but they're now the same in v3.2. The id difference may also have been due to your access token, try using a page-scoped access token so that `/me` returns the expected page.

1. I've been able to list existing conversations and their end users at `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/conversations?fields=id,participants&access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` (senders field can also be used too)
2. I've used the `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` to post a message using the JSON `{ recipient: { id: "<PSID>"}, message: { text: "message" }}` where PSID is the id from the participants id field (not the the thread id).
3. The message appears in the existing thread and all future replies show up in both the webhook and existing the existing conversation thread.